# The socket closes after 3 minutes after putting the application in the background

Tags: swift, ios7, asyncsocket, gcdasyncsocket

I am using "GCDAsyncSocket" in my project. My project A video conversation project using the Linphone library. And I also use socket connection. The application only works between devices connected to the local modem.

The socket I use in my application closes 3 minutes after entering the application background. I want the socket not to close as long as the application is running (unless the application is killed). My application doesn't have a backend. All communication, except for Linphone, only takes place via the socket.

How can I do that?

I've tried

```
func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didAcceptNewSocket newSocket: GCDAsyncSocket) {
    print("connect succuess")
    print("connect to" + newSocket.connectedHost!)
    print("port" + String(newSocket.connectedPort))
    clients.append(newSocket)
    callIP = newSocket.connectedHost!
    sock.enableBackgroundingOnSocket()

    newSocket.readData(withTimeout: -1, tag: 0)
}
```

Comment: When your application goes into background mode you only have a limited time to continue doing things before the app is suspended. Other than that you can utilise the supported [background modes](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: I tried them but it didn't work. The important thing here is that I am using GCDAsyncSocket. Thanks

Comment: I dont think it matters what you use. you cannot keep your app running constantly in the background.

Comment: unless the application is closed. I want the application to run as long as it stays in the background when the user presses the home button.